# sbt and play test with @RunWith

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt, junit4

I'm dealing with a problem working on a *Play* project and *sbt*.
The problem is:

- I have tests, some of them are using `PowerMockito`, some of them aren't
- For the tests using `PowerMockito`, I've added `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` at the beginning of the class.
- For the tests not using, I've added nothing.

Here is an example for a test that uses `PowerMockito`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeMockedClass.class})
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        PowerMockito
               .stub(PowerMockito.method(SomeMockedClass.class, "aMethod"))
               .toReturn(something);
        assertThat(someCall).isEqualTo(something);
    }
}
```

Here is an example for a test that doesn't use `PowerMockito`

```
public class AnotherClassTest {

    @Test
    public void anotherTest(){
        assertThat(something).isEqualTo(something);
    }
}
```

And here is my `build.sbt` dep:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ... 
  // Testing
  "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert" % "1.4" % "test",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test",
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-mockito-release-full" % "1.6.2" % "test",
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent" % "1.6.2" % "test",
  "org.easymock" % "easymock" % "3.3.1" % "test",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
)
```

Here is the **problem**:

- When I run my tests from IntelliJ, it founds all tests and everything is ok
- When I run my tests from activator (`activator test`), it does **NOT** found the tests with the `@RunWith`.

I've read some post about it, like the `sbt version` or something 
(even https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt/issues/15).

But the *sbt version* is : *0.13.8-M5* so it seems ok.
*Play version* is : *2.3.8*

If you guys have any clue that'd be great.
Thanks